# Duplication of interface error in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am not even sure how to start. 
I am developing an iPhone application with the latest `Xcode` and sdk using core plot and the core async socket library. Everything was fine until a few hours ago, when Xcode dumped a ton of **"interface duplication"** errors for no apparent reason.
The two files that are emitting errors are the `AsyncSocket.h` and an API client that I wrote in order to get data out of the target server.
The errors are the following:

- Nested Redefinition error on all enums in `AsyncSocket.h` and my API client.
- Redeclaration of enum on all enumerations in `AsyncSocket.h` and my API client.
- Duplicate interface declaration on the `AsyncSocket.h` and the API client's interface file.
- The error occurred between two builds of the application. **NOTHING** was changed during that time which is why I can't even begin to think what is causing this.

The API client is a really simple thing, it just uses the async socket to send queries to the server and then return the parsed results in arrays. Nothing complicated, as I am not that into objective c yet.
I wish I could give some more useful information but that is all I have.

Comment: Without showing your code, you're unlikely to get useful answers. First try a complete rebuild (clean then build). If that doesn't fix the problem, try to reproduce the problem with a small amount of code, and post it.

Comment: I am trying to duplicate the problem with a small, manageable amount of code but it does not seem possible; The problem randomly disappears at some point, getting replaced by different issues (like saying that classes that are clearly in the project aren't). Then at some point the target gets started in the iPad simulator while it clearly is marked as an iPhone application. I suspect that the issue is related to core plot, but removing it does not fix the problem. This is really frustrating.

Comment: I have something similar. I added an entry to an enum and since then I have 'nested redefinition of enum' errors and "Duplicate interface" warnings on the category, in the header of which I declared the enum. Everything worked up 'till then nothing material was changed. Very distressing. Do you use Xcode 4? It seems to me I never had this stuff with Xcode 3. In my case it's an "LLVM GCC 4.2" error (and warnings).

Comment: Not sure how I hit this one,but I did.. for me the fix seemed to be doing a Clean (Product->Clean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe your problem results from a simple mistake. In the header file you begin with:

```
@interface ClassName : SuperclassName
```

while in the .m file you do:

```
@interface ClassName ()
```

When you forget the brackets, the compiler complains.

I hope this helps. Best wishes with your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the response above put me on the right track.

I created a new enum record in a .h file I use for all my Constants.

But I forgot to add the semi-colon on the end.  This simple little syntax error resulted in some weird and confusing errors appearing on files other than the one which contained the error.

No doubt you've resolved this by now but it might fix someone else's issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the "Duplicate interface definition" error message and traced it to my having put an "#include xxx.h" in a header (.h) file instead of in the .m file where I intended to put it.

Comment: Do you mean `#include` or `#import`? `#import` behaves a little differently; it tells the preprocessor to include the header only once.